# Adding tooltips with different formats for different series

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I have a combo chart with an x-axis of type 'date' and two y-axes (one represented by line, the other by bars). By default the tooltips for both series is displayed in this format:

```
[Date] (MMM dd, y)
[series title]: [value]
```

I would like the tooltip for the bar series to be displayed with a different format though:

```
[Date] (MMM y)
[series title]: [value]
```

How do I change the date format in the tooltip for just one of the series? I tried changing it with the format() method:

```
var formatter = new google.visualization.DateFormat({pattern: 'MMM y'});
formatter.format(data, 0);
```

but that changed the format for tooltips of both series.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual implementation of the feature could be a bit lengthy (I'd guess 1+ hours for an experienced Google Charts API Developer, possibly a day for someone inexperienced.)

I can however point you in the right direction. If you take a look at the documentation for [Custom HTML Tooltips](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/customizing_tooltip_content#customizing-html-content), the second example shows using a function to render the output.  If you do something similar (it doesn't have to be an HTML tooltip, but you might as well), then you can pass your JavaScript `Date` object to the function and format it yourself for just the tooltip.  This formatting would not change your axis formats.

Note: The example with the function rendering the HTML for the tooltip has a lot more than just that going on.  They are using the `focusTarget: 'category'` option which make hovering focus on the whole row's worth of data, instead of just the one pair of x, y values. To have custom tooltips for each series, you will need a tooltip column for each data column. There are other pieces in the docs that show how to set up DataTables for tooltips. How you will actually write this depends a lot on how you are importing your data.

Your format method signature will probably look something like this: `formatTooltip(columnName, date, value)`, or too make it more generic: `formatTooptip(dateFormatString, date, value)`. Good luck!